# Why does Keras pad_sequences not work twice in the same code?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to preprocess some texts using Keras, and I need to use the  `keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences()` function more than once, however it does not seem to allow it. Is there a way to get around this error and use the function more than once?

```
import numpy
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

example_sequences = [[1,2,3,4],[1,5,4],[2,3]]
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 3

pad_sequences = pad_sequences(example_sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
print(pad_sequences)

sequences2 = [[1,2,3,4],[1,5,4],[2,3]]
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH2 = 3

pad_sequences2 = pad_sequences(sequences2, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH2)
```

Output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
[[2 3 4]
 [1 5 4]
 [0 2 3]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test.py", line 47, in <module>
    pad_sequences2 = pad_sequences(sequences2, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH2)
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

As you can see the first time the function is called it produces a matrix, however, the second time it is called I get the error that a numpy.ndarray is not callable. Notice that the input for the pad_sequences function is identical, and no input is a numpy array. So why do I not get the same output from the function and how do I fix this so that I can use the pad_sequences function more than once?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the output of the first `pad_sequences` to a variable named `pad_sequences`:

```
pad_sequences = pad_sequences(example_sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
print(pad_sequences)  # "pad_sequences" is now a Numpy array!
```

Hence, by the time you reach the second "call" to `pad_sequences`, it is actually a Numpy array:

```
pad_sequences2 = pad_sequences(sequences2, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH2)
```

Simply rename the output variable, e.g.

```
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(example_sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
print(padded_sequences)
```

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. Such a simple mistake, I can't believe I didn't see that. My code works now, thank you for your help!

Comment: @sockerkakor: If it helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer. Thanks!